# google cloud vm instance does not listen to external or internal ip adresses

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a java spring framework back end which also contains rest api . I deployed successfully the app in vm instance google cloud platform, after connecting eclipse with google cloud platform. I downloaded googlecloussdkinatller for that. At the beginning, when I tried to run: https://industrial-net-242708.appspot.com/..., I got a 404 error: not found . When I ran this one: https://35.228.187.51:80 , I got:
''' This site can’t be reached 35.228.187.51 refused to connect. '''

Then I changed my spring aplication to spring boot and I got this error : 500 or when I ran this one from the ssh terminal: https://35.228.187.51:80 , I got connection error time.
I have also created http, https (80, 443) ports in firewall rules - vpc network fot the vm instance.
Then I ran the netstat -l command in the ssh terminal and the result was :
'''

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 instance-education-:ntp 0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ntp             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fea6:ntp [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10254    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9003     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9015     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10299    /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9020     /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     9141     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13840    /tmp/ssh-1toYloB0sh/agent.973
```

'''

If I understand this correctly , the vm is not listening to ip adresses (external, internal) this is why I am getting the error. Do you know what I could do to fix it ? 
My java application runs in a google cloud server debian 9 / linux . 
My computer has Windows 10 as an OS>. Any help appreciated

Comment: 1) A 404 error means that your instance is responding. 2) You cannot access App Engine using IP addresses unless you add the HTTP "Host: [DOMAIN_NAME]" header.

Comment: @John Hanley    Can you explain how do I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean "how do I do that"?

Comment: @John Hanley  Where should I add that ? and how ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please be specific.

Comment: @ohn Hanley I mean that I have opened my ssh terminal for the vm instance gcp and I am executing there commands. You said that I needed to add the HTTP "Host: [DOMAIN_NAME]" header. How do I add this header ? Is there a command that I need to execute ? or do I need to make a change in the google cloud app engine ??

Comment: Basically I need to tell my vm to listen to specifics ports in order to accept requests. @John Hanley

Comment: You made an edit, so maybe you know something @Denis T.

Comment: It depends on how you are accessing the instance. Use the domain name and not an IP address. If you use an IP address you must add an HTTP header to the request. Google search what that means and then apply to the tool or the code.